# python - handling HTTP requests asynchronously

Tags: python, django, httprequest, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I need to generate a PDF report for each entry of a django queryset. There'll be between between 30k and 40k entries.

The PDF is generated through an external API. Since currently is generated on demand, this is handled synchronously via an HTTP request/response.
That will be different for this task, since I think I'll use a django management command to loop through the queryset and perform the PDF generation.

Which approach should I follow for this task? I thought about 2 possibile solutions, although are technologies that I never used:

1) [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.task.http.html): assign a task (http request with a different payload) to a worker, then retrieve it once it's done.

2) [request-futures](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-futures): using requests in a non-blocking way.

the goal is to use the API concurrently (e.g. send 10 or 100 http requests simultaneously, depending on how many concurrent requests the API can handle).

Anybody here that handled a similar task and can give advices on how to proceed on this?

The following is a first attempt, made with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) (NOTE: most of the code is reused and not written by myself, as I took ownership of this project. ):

```
class Checker(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... various setup

    # other methods
    # .....

    def run_single(self, uuid, verbose=False):
        """
        run a single PDF generation and local download
        """
        start = timer()
        headers = self.headers

        data, obj = self.get_review_data(uuid)
        if verbose: 
            print("** Report: {} **".format(obj))
        response = requests.post(
            url=self.endpoint_url,
            headers=headers,
            data=json.dumps(data)
        )
        if verbose:
            print('POST - Response: {} \n {} \n {} secs'.format(
                response.status_code,
                response.content,
                response.elapsed.total_seconds())
            )
        run_url = self.check_progress(post_response=response, verbose=True)
        if run_url:
            self.get_file(run_url, obj, verbose=True)
        print("*** Download {}in {} secs".format("(verbose) " if verbose else "", timer()-start))


    def run_all(self, uuids, verbose=True):
        start = timer()
        for obj_uuid in review_uuids:
            self.run_single(obj_uuid, verbose=verbose)
        print("\n\n### Downloaded {}{} reviews in {} secs".format(
            "(verbose) " if verbose else "",
            len(uuids),
            timer() - start)
        )

    def run_all_multi(self, uuids, workers=4, verbose=True):
        pool = Pool(processes=workers)
        pool.map(self.run_single, uuids)


    def check_progress(self, post_response, attempts_limit=10000, verbose=False):
        """
        check the progress of PDF generation querying periodically the API endpoint
        """
        if post_response.status_code != 200:
            if verbose: print("POST response status code != 200 - exit")
            return None
        url = 'https://apidomain.com/{path}'.format(
            domain=self.domain,
            path=post_response.json().get('links', {}).get('self', {}).get('href'),
            headers = self.headers
        )
        job_id = post_response.json().get('jobId', '')
        status = 'Running'
        attempt_counter = 0
        start = timer()
        if verbose: 
            print("GET - url: {}".format(url))
        while status == 'Running':
            attempt_counter += 1
            job_response = requests.get(
                url=url,
                headers=self.headers,
            )
            job_data = job_response.json()
            status = job_data['status']
            message = job_data['message']
            progress = job_data['progress']
            if status == 'Error':
                if verbose:
                    end = timer()
                    print(
                        '{sc} - job_id: {job_id} - error_id: [{error_id}]: {message}'.format(
                            sc=job_response.status_code, 
                            job_id=job_id,
                            error_id=job_data['errorId'], 
                            message=message
                        ), '{} secs'.format(end - start)
                    )
                    print('Attempts: {} \n {}% progress'.format(attempt_counter, progress))
                return None
            if status == 'Complete':
                if verbose:
                    end = timer()
                    print('run_id: {run_id} - Complete - {secs} secs'.format(
                        run_id=run_id,
                        secs=end - start)
                    )
                    print('Attempts: {}'.format(attempt_counter))
                    print('{url}/files/'.format(url=url))
                return '{url}/files/'.format(url=url)
            if attempt_counter >= attempts_limit:
                if verbose:
                    end = timer()
                    print('File failed to generate after {att_limit} retrieve attempts: ({progress}% progress)' \
                          ' - {message}'.format(
                              att_limit=attempts_limit,
                              progress=int(progress * 100),
                              message=message
                          ), '{} secs'.format(end-start))
                return None
            if verbose:
                print('{}% progress  - attempts: {}'.format(progress, attempt_counter), end='\r')
                sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
        if verbose:
            end = timer()
            print(status, 'message: {} - attempts: {} - {} secs'.format(message, attempt_counter, end - start))
        return None

    def get_review_data(self, uuid, host=None, protocol=None):
        review = get_object_or_404(MyModel, uuid)
        internal_api_headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(
                review.employee.csod_profile.csod_user_token
            )
        }

        data = requests.get(
            url=a_local_url,
            params={'format': 'json', 'indirect': 'true'},
            headers=internal_api_headers,
        ).json()
        return (data, review)

    def get_file(self, runs_url, obj, verbose=False):

        runs_files_response = requests.get(
            url=runs_url,
            headers=self.headers,
            stream=True,
        )

        runs_files_data = runs_files_response.json()


        file_path = runs_files_data['files'][0]['links']['file']['href'] # remote generated file URI
        file_response_url = 'https://apidomain.com/{path}'.format(path=file_path)
        file_response = requests.get(
            url=file_response_url,
            headers=self.headers,
            params={'userId': settings.CREDENTIALS['userId']},
            stream=True,
        )
        if file_response.status_code != 200:
            if verbose:
                print('error in retrieving file for {r_id}\nurl: {url}\n'.format(
                    r_id=obj.uuid, url=file_response_url)
                )
        local_file_path = '{temp_dir}/{uuid}-{filename}-{employee}.pdf'.format(
            temp_dir=self.local_temp_dir,
            uuid=obj.uuid,
            employee=slugify(obj.employee.get_full_name()),
            filename=slugify(obj.task.name)
        )
        with open(local_file_path, 'wb') as f:
            for block in file_response.iter_content(1024):
                f.write(block)
            if verbose:
                print('\n --> {r} [{uuid}]'.format(r=review, uuid=obj.uuid))
                print('\n --> File downloaded: {path}'.format(path=local_file_path))

    @classmethod
    def get_temp_directory(self):
        """
        generate a local unique temporary directory
        """
        return '{temp_dir}/'.format(
            temp_dir=mkdtemp(dir=TEMP_DIR_PREFIX),
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uuids = #list or generator of objs uuids
    checker = Checker()
    checker.run_all_multi(uuids=uuids)
```

Unfortunately, running `checker.run_all_multi` have the following effects

- the python shell freeze;
- no output is printed;
- no file is generated;
- I have to kill the console from command line, the normal keyboard interrupt stops to work

while running `checker.run_all` does the job normally (one by one).

Any suggestion specifically about why this code doesn't work (and not about what I could use instead of multiprocessing)?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: How often you need to generate these reports? Will the generation be triggered manually or automatically?

Comment: - once a year
- manually

Comment: at that frequency I'd be inclined to look at using requests-futures and dodging the need to setup rabbitmq etc

Comment: @Anentropic Could you be more specific or provide any sample/PoC? Thanks

Comment: Celery is probably easier to code on the python side, but you have to install and configure additional software (an MQ e.g. rabbit, plus run celery worker processes).  requests-futures will be a simpler system (just a python script), but you probably have to do some sort of rate-limiting in your python code to avoid sending off 40k requests to the PDF service

Comment: another approach would be just a plain old multiprocessing Pool... this task won't be cpu bound and it's easy to control your concurrency that way

Comment: for a once-a-year task that isn't supporting millions of users in real time just pick whatever looks easiest to you and start coding it :)

Answer (score 1):

With your frequency, once a year & manually. You don't need Celery or request-futures.

Create a method like

```
def record_to_pdf(record):
    # create pdf from record
```

Then create a management command with code (using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers))

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=NUMBER_OF_CORES)
pool.map(record_to_pdf, YOUR_QUERYSET)
```

Management command will not be asynchronous though. To make it asynchronous you can run it in the background.

Also, if your processes is not CPU bound (like, it is only calling some API) then as @Anentropic suggested you can experiment with higher number of processes when creating pool.

Comment: for a task that's not cpu-bound you can also experiment with number of prcoesses > NUMBER_OF_CORES

Comment: @Anentropic you are right, it the method `record_to_pdf` is only calling some API then number of processes can be increased by a significant number (bound by network speed and API rate limiting).

Comment: Tried. It doens't output anything to stdout, it doesn't save any file to destination directory, and also freeze the shell (I need to kill it with kill -9).
the same code works without multiprocessing, processing every item sequentially.
I can paste the code. Any ideas?

Comment: @Luke please post the code by editing your question.